# Standalone Swagger UI: display only specific endpoint

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I am planning to use a standalone Swagger UI for generating multi-page API documentation.

Right now, I am able to show all the endpoints on same page with a basic configuration.

How do I config a standalone Swagger UI to show only specific endpoint so I can span the documentation across multiple pages?

I found 'filter' option, but it acts like a search rather than a display filter.

Comment: This is not supported out-of-the-box, but some people shared workarounds and plugins here: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/6031#issuecomment-762887320. Alternatively, consider using another doc renderer, e.g. one of https://openapi.tools/#documentation

Comment: I saw that workaround, but it is seems to be for React version and not for standalone one. I will check out other generators, thanks!